# Better way (functional / immutable, but performant) to code an algorithm which eliminates items from a set along the way

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, immutability

I'm somewhat of a beginner to Scala and functional programming, and I have some algorithm code that may have some smell because it uses mutability, but also has a bug, partly due to it being mutable. I have two sets of 2D points. Each point from set 1 is to be correlated to the closest point in set 2 (given a scale and offset for set 1 relative to set 2). We want 1-to-1 correlations but not 1-to-multiple. This I think implies that as we find the closest point in set 2 to a point in set 1, we should remove the former from (a copy of) set 2 since we do not wish to match it again. However perhaps there is an immutable/functional way...

The code below has a bug in that if all of the points are removed from set2NotYetMatched, then we are calling empty.minBy; this can be fixed by reworking the code to be even less functional, perhaps with a for or while construct. But before I do that, is there a better way to code? Here is the current code:

```
  protected def calcDistanceCostBetweenSets(
        set1: Seq[Point], set1StartX: Double, set1XScale: Double, set2Window: PointWindow, xImportance: Double
        ): CloudMatch = {

    require (!set1.isEmpty)

    var set2NotYetMatched = scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty ++= set2Window.subsetWithMargins

    val correlations = set1 map(set1Point => {
      val minDistPointAndDist = set2NotYetMatched.map(set2Point =>
        (
          set2Point,
          DistanceCostCalculator.calcPointToPointDistanceSquared(
            set1Point, set2Point, set1StartX, set2Window.marginStartX, set1XScale, xImportance)))
        .minBy(_._2)

      set2NotYetMatched -= ( minDistPointAndDist._1)
      new PointCorrelation(set1Point, Collections.singletonList(minDistPointAndDist._1), minDistPointAndDist._2)
    })
    val distanceCost = correlations.map(_.getCost).foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
    return new CloudMatch(
      set2Window.firstPointAlongX,
      set2Window.startIndexInOriginalSubset,
      distanceCost,
      Lists.newArrayList(JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(correlations)))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach is to use `foldLeft` to keep track of the current correlations and the elements in set2 that remain.

See below for the `findCorrelations` method. It's similar to your recursive solution. One notable difference is that you don't have to maintain `remainingSet`. What do you think?

```
private def findCorrelations(
  set1: Set[Point], 
  set1StartX: Double, 
  set1XScale: Double, 
  set2Points: Set[Point], 
  set2StartX: Double, 
  xImportance: Double
): List[EventCorrelation] = {

  def calculateCost(p1: Point, p2: Point): Double = {
    DistanceCostCalculator.calcPointToPointDistanceSquared(
      p1, p2,
      set1StartX, set2StartX, set1XScale, xImportance)
  }

  set1.foldLeft((List.empty[EventCorrelation], set2Points)) { 
    case ((correlationsAcc, set2PointsRemaining), set1PointToFind) =>
      if (set2PointsRemaining.isEmpty) {
        correlationsAcc
      } else {
        val (set2MinPoint, minDist) = set2PointsRemaining.map(scorePoint =>
          (scorePoint, calculateCost(set1PointToFind, scorePoint))
        ).minBy(_._2)

        val correlation = new EventCorrelation(
          set1PointToFind, 
          Collections.singletonList(set2MinPoint),
          minDist)

        (correlationsAcc + correlation, set2PointsRemaining - set2MinPoint)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting and elegant! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While I'm interested in better answers, I came up with a much better solution using a **recursive** algorithm (no mutabilities), with tail recursion, where an item is removed each recursion:

```
  protected def calcDistanceCostBetweenSets(set1: Seq[Point], set1StartX: Double, set1XScale: Double, set2Window: PointWindow, xImportance: Double): CloudMatch = {
    require (!set1.isEmpty)

    val correlations = findCorrelations(set1.toSet, set1StartX, set1XScale, set2Window.subsetWithMargins.toSet, set2Window.startX, xImportance)
    val distanceCost = correlations.map(_.getCost).foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
    new CloudMatch(
      set2Window.firstPoint,
      set2Window.startIndexInOriginalSubset,
      distanceCost,
      Lists.newArrayList(JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(correlations sortBy(_.getActualEvent.getStartX))))
  }

  private def findCorrelations(set1: Set[Point], set1StartX: Double, set1XScale: Double, set2Points: Set[Point], set2StartX: Double, xImportance: Double
                              ): List[EventCorrelation] = {
    findCorrelations(Nil, set1, set1 head, set2Points,
      DistanceCostCalculator.calcPointToPointDistanceSquared(_, _,
        set1StartX, set2StartX, set1XScale, xImportance))
  }

  private def findCorrelations(
                                correlations: List[EventCorrelation],
                                set1: Set[Point],
                                set1PointToFind: Point,
                                set2: Set[Point],
                                calculateCost : (Point, Point) => Double
                              ): List[EventCorrelation] = {

    val minDistPoint = set2.map(scorePoint =>
      (scorePoint, calculateCost(set1PointToFind, scorePoint))
    ).minBy(_._2)

    val correlation = new EventCorrelation(set1PointToFind, Collections.singletonList(minDistPoint._1), minDistPoint._2)
    val remainingSet1 = set1 - set1PointToFind;
    val remainingSet2 = set2 - minDistPoint._1

    if(remainingSet1.isEmpty || remainingSet2.isEmpty) correlations
    else findCorrelations(
      correlation :: correlations,
      remainingSet1,
      remainingSet1 head,
      remainingSet2,
      calculateCost);
  }
```